# Request Certificate CA

Tags: windows-server-2008, certificate, certificate-authority, pki

I have a Windows server configured as a Certificate Authority (CA).

When requesting a certificate via https://server/certServ and choosing the template to request (Request Certificate->Advance Certifcate Request) I do not get all the options to fill in the certificate

[image: img1]

it should look like this

[image: img2]

Thanks

Comment: You use template for Subordinate CA. Use template for standard certificate.

Comment: The web UI sucks, at some point I did not even install that server component. Do it over the CLI, works way better

Comment: What browser are you using?  You can only get the 2nd one if you use IE if I recall.

Comment: It happens to me with all certificates.
The browser I use is Edge
What do you mean it doesn't go into the advanced options?